# Issue with while loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hello everyone below is data in my text file

```
DEC/08/2017 00:00:00|DEC/03/2017 00:00:00|ALL|ALL|Testing ALL condition|G800162|Y|12
NOV/08/2017 22:37:00|NOV/09/2017 00:38:00|SWETR|ARETC|CRQ changes.|G800162|Y|11
NOV/08/2017 23:30:00|NOV/09/2017 00:15:00|PHLSR|ARETC|Customer connectivity issue|G800162|Y|35
NOV/18/2017 00:29:00|NOV/19/2017 11:10:00|ABWSE|GBRVF|Checking Update from Script.|G800162|Y|12
NOV/08/2017 22:47:00|NOV/09/2017 00:37:00|ALL|ALL|Testing VPMN and HPMN as ALL|G800162|Y|12
NOV/08/2017 20:46:00|NOV/08/2017 21:30:00|ALL|ARETC|Checking with 8th Date|G800162|Y|16
NOV/08/2017 20:47:00|NOV/08/2017 22:30:00|ALL|ARETC|Checking with 8th Date|G800162|Y|12
NOV/19/2017 10:38:00|NOV/19/2017 12:03:00|KWTKT|ALL|testing if condition.|G800162|Y|26
NOV/08/2017 22:40:00|NOV/09/2017 00:36:00|ALL|ARETC|Testing IF COND|G800162|Y|12
```

I'm using `IFS` to separate the fields and passing values to variables using cut command. untill passing variable everything is good. In If condition when `VPMN` and `HPMN` both are `ALL` then only below update query should execute. i see if any one condition is satisfied update query is executing.

```
while IFS='|' read -r row || [[ -n $row ]];
do
[ -z "$row" ] && continue

IN_TIME=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f1`
OUT_TIME=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f2`
VPMN=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f3`
HPMN=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f4`
REMARKS=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f5`
USER_ID=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f6`
EXCLUSION_FLAG=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f7`
EXCLUDE_CODE=`echo $row |cut -d'|' -f8`
if ( VPMN="ALL"  &&  HPMN="ALL" )
then
echo "update  XXXXXX.YYYYYY set remarks='$REMARKS',user_id='$USER_ID',exclusion_flag='$EXCLUSION_FLAG',exclude_code='$EXCLUDE_CODE' where  out_time between to_date('$IN_TIME','MON/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('$OUT_TIME','MON/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); " >updatenrtpmnsql.sql
fi
```

done

Comment: This might help: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: There are situations where `while read -r` cannot be avoided, but this is not one of them. I would *strongly* suggest looking into Awk for this task. Learning another language might seem like a tall order, but it's really part of learning to use the shell properly - there are specialized tools for specialized tasks, and you use the shell mainly to glue them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `if ( VPMN="ALL"  &&  HPMN="ALL" )` is just wrong, in a way it is using

1. Using wrong operators for string comparison `(..)` is not a construct defined for running operations within a sub-shell.
2. The variables `VPMN` and `HPMN` are not used in the comparison, what you are doing in the statement is assigning the values to those variables in the if condition which will *always* be true. You need to check the value of those variables.

Your condition needs to be something like,

```
if [ "$VPMN" = "ALL" ] && [ "$HPMN" = "ALL" ]
```

---

Aside from the current topic, always lower-case names for user defined variables to not be confused with the system environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` with `IFS` is a little awkward. With arrays and `IFS` instead:

```
while IFS='|' read -ra cols; do
  in_time=${cols[0]}
  out_time=${cols[1]}
  vpmn=${cols[2]}
  hpmn=${cols[3]}
  if [[ "$vpmn" == "ALL" ]] && [[ "$hpmn" == "ALL" ]]; then echo "$vpmn:$hpmn"; fi
done < input_file
```

Comment: It is a lot cleaner to skip the array and just name the variables directly in the read command.  eg `while IFS=\| read in_time out_time vpmn ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, it is totally subjective which one is cleaner. Consider also the cases where you don't really need all the columns but just an arbitrary subset.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely missing the point of setting IFS for read, since you are not using it to separate the fields.  What you meant is:

```
while IFS='|' read in_time out_time vpmn hpmn remarks user_id exclusion_flag exclude_code; do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`( VPMN="ALL"  &&  HPMN="ALL" )` is not a conditional, but a *subshell*.
This subshell always exits with status 0,
and when used in an `if` the condition always evaluates to true,
causing the behavior that you're observing.

Write like this:

```
if [[ $VPMN = "ALL" ]] && [[ $HPMN = "ALL" ]]
```

Also, the loop is extremely inefficient,
because it runs a `cut` process for every column.
It can be vastly improved by using `read` itself,
to store the columns directly in the right variables,
thanks to the given `IFS`:

```
while IFS='|' read -r in_time out_time vpmn hpmn remarks user_id exclusion_flag exclude_code _; do
    [[ $in_time ]] || continue

    if [[ $vpmn = ALL ]] && [[ $hpmn = ALL ]]
    then
        echo "update  XXXXXX.YYYYYY set remarks='$remarks',user_id='$user_id',exclusion_flag='$exclusion_flag',exclude_code='$exclude_code' where  out_time between to_date('$in_time','MON/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('$out_time','MON/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); "
    fi
done
```

Note that I renamed all variables from SHOUT_CASE to lower case,
because this is the recommended practice.
SHOUT_CASE is a convention (by POSIX standard) for system variables.

Comment: Uppercase is reserved for *system* variables, per POSIX. You'd use lowercase even for a global, if it's your own private global.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for the precision